# JS: Download to excel rows in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have a download as excel button and it will download a table for the user but I'm trying to add a way they can tick a tick box and download the ticked rows. I have the tick box adding a Class of download to the TR how can I edit the JS I have to just download the TR with the class of download?

My JS for my download:

```
$(document).on('click', '.download', function (event) {
    fnExcelReport()
});
function fnExcelReport()
{
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr>";
    var textRange; var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('main-table');

    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 
        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
    }  
    else
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  
    return (sa);
}
```

Comment: there's no php here, it's JS, what's the relation? there's no code to support the tag. --- *"how can I edit the PHP...?"* - what php is that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have edit the post, I'm working on 2 things at the same time. Sorry

Comment: Ah, ok Ryan and no worries. Well TBH, I am so not the guy for this. JS and me just don't speak to each very well *lol*. I'm mostly a serverside coder. Let's see if anyone else can pick up on it.

Comment: You could use jQuery's `.each()` function to loop through and find each checked box when the click occurs and perform the download. Click -> loop -> is this checked? -> download.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Where would I use this? I'm quite new at all this

Comment: You would have to write the code yourself.